# Should I close a file with file.close() when there is a FileNotFoundError exception?

Tags: python, file, file-not-found

I'm trying to open a file in python and print a message when the file doesn't exist. But I'm confused whether to close the file or not when the exception happens.

```
    try:
        file = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
        file.close() # should I do this?
    except OSError:
        print(f"{sys.argv[1]} file not found.")
```

Comment: Yes, you can close here.   Better to close after the try/except though if you want to actually use the file!


Better still, use the `with` statement.
     `with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler method of checking if a file exists:

```
import os

if not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
    print(f"{sys.argv[1]} file not found.")
```

But to answer your question, the ```file.close()`` happens only when the file exists and you successfully open the file.  Not when the exception occurs.

Edit:
As pointed out by @ekhumoro,  the above has a race condition (when other processes access that file).  If no other process accesses that file, then the above code works.

Solution is as @ekhumoro pointed out is to use your original try/except method.

Comment: okay, when the file exists where should I close it? Is my code above already correct?

Comment: Yes, eventually you should close it.   It all depends on what you need to do with it.

Comment: @ewong Your method is vulnerable to a race condition, because the file could be deleted by another process immediately after the if-check. Using try/except avoids that problem entirely. It's also better to use `with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as file`, since that will automatically close the file (if necessary) even if there's io-errors.